# Can't add entities when forcing the ID to be explicitly set under EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2

I want to do seed and I execute something like this in my controller.

```
Member member = new Member { Id = MemberId1, UserName = "member1" };
Context. Add(member);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

This produces the error telling me that the explicit setting of IDs isn't allowed. I get this and why it's so but since the entries are my seed, I need to do it anyway. According to [this blog](https://entityframeworkcore.com/saving-data-identity-insert), I can temporarily turn the checking off like this.

```
Member member = new Member { Id = MemberId1, UserName = "member1" };
Context. Add(member);
Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT blipp.Members ON");
Context.SaveChanges();
Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT blipp.Members OFF");
```

Well, would you know, that produces the error telling me that there's nothing to be set, despite me having `entity.HasKey(e => e.Id)` in my config. I'm a bit lost here what to do.

> 'Table 'blipp.Members' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation.'

The same happens when I try this in the DB directly too. I can't do the seed using `HasData()` in the usual way due to limitations of the EF and owned entities. The original error is this.

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Actions' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

What do I do here?

Comment: This is how to do data seeding in EF-core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding. Then EF will automatically respect identity columns.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for the suggestion. Regrettably, that doesn't work with owned entities, very well. There are workarounds but nothing that's smooth, sadly.

Comment: No, it's not smooth, but the alternative isn't nice either. To make `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` work you have to manage your own transaction. I'd use seeding the way it's supposed to be done.

Comment: @GertArnold I agree with you completely. Regrettably, at the moment, it's not possible to seed when using owned entities and n-to-m relations without navigation properties and lazy loading. I understand that this specific combo is rather advanced and is tress again - I completely agree that one should follow the standard best-practices and not horse around making home-brewed solutions. Also, as it turns out, I somehow can insert the entities with explicit IDs now **without OFF'ing**. Still, for academic curiosity's sake - do you have a shot at this specific question?